# How to reflash/reformat enterprise Aladdin eToken Pro Java 72k for own certificate?

Tags: single-sign-on, hardware-token

Is [this eToken](http://csrc.nist.rip/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140sp/140sp1135.pdf) can be reformatted or re-flashed for using as smart-card for authentication? 
I have this stick left from my former work and wanna re-use it some way, for example, for authentication in laptop. Is there a way?

Comment: This is a commercial product. Questions about support for this product under specific OS should be directed to the vendor.

Comment: Yes, I am aware but this product used in enterprise environments with a strict use-cases, and I am asking about of non-standard case of using this tool so I suppose it fits "security tools" point among [allowed](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Kaspersky is also commercial product but there are [a bunch of questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=kaspersky) here about it.

Comment: "Is X supported by Windows?" is not a security question.

Comment: This new version is again solely answerable by the vendor.